# output of fields with bibtex/biber depending on the document language

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

I have bibtex entries containing the following information:

```
@book{AEEHHL2003a-ed,
    address = {Berlin},
    booktitle = {{Dependenz und Valenz} / {Dependency} and Valency: {Ein internationales Handbuch der zeitgenössischen Forschung} / {An} International Handbook of Contemporary Research},
    doi = {10.1515/9783110141900.1},
    editor = {Ágel, Vilmos and Eichinger, Ludwig M. and Eroms, Hans-Werner and Hellwig, Peter and Heringer, Hans Jürgen and Lobin, Henning},
    number = {25},
    publisher = walterdegruyter,
    series = {Handbücher zur Sprach- und Kommunikationswissenschaft},
    title = {{Dependenz und Valenz} / {Dependency} and Valency: {Ein internationales Handbuch der zeitgenössischen Forschung} / {An} International Handbook of Contemporary Research},
   volume = {1},
   year = {2003}}
```

Booktitle and also series (not shown here) contain German and English parts. One often finds all of this in the list of references, but I guess it would make more sense to have just the English information in an English book an the German information in German books.

An additional aspect is that these items are crossreferenced by others. So duplicating the item with an English and German variant would make the duplication of other items necessary as well.

I thought about writing a command \gereng{German text}{English text} that prints the correct language depending on some language flag. But this would interfere with capitalization and other stuff. So: question: is there a better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a nice application of the planned 'multiscript' feature. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/416. A development version is available (https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/experimental/ and https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/experimental/), but the feature and its implementation are not mature enough yet for the release version.

While you are waiting for the feature to become available the easiest way to emulate it is probably via `@string` or `@xdata` entries and separate `.bib` files. You evidently know how to use `@string` (`publisher = walterdegruyter,`), so the example below only shows `@xdata`.

In addition to your main `.bib` file you will need as many auxiliary `.bib` files as languages you intend to support. In this case we have one auxiliary `.bib` file for English and one for German.

Extract the multilingual fields of your entry into separate entries of the same name in the auxiliary `.bib` files. Translate the fields accordingly, then reference the `@xdata` entry in the entry in your main `.bib` file.

You can then switch languages by choosing which of the auxiliary `.bib` files you include with `\addbibresource`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-xdata-de.bib}
@xdata{AEEHHL2003a-ed-xdata,
  title    = {Dependenz und Valenz},
  subtitle = {Ein internationales Handbuch der zeitgenössischen Forschung},
  langid   = {ngerman},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-xdata-en.bib}
@xdata{AEEHHL2003a-ed-xdata,
  title    = {Dependency and Valency},
  subtitle = {An International Handbook of Contemporary Research},
  langid   = {english},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{AEEHHL2003a-ed,
  xdata     = {AEEHHL2003a-ed-xdata},
  address   = {Berlin},
  doi       = {10.1515/9783110141900.1},
  editor    = {Ágel, Vilmos and Eichinger, Ludwig M.
               and Eroms, Hans-Werner and Hellwig, Peter
               and Heringer, Hans Jürgen and Lobin, Henning},
  number    = {25},
  publisher = {De Gruyter},
  series    = {Handbücher zur Sprach- und Kommunikationswissenschaft},
  volume    = {1},
  year      = {2003},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-xdata-en.bib}
%\addbibresource{\jobname-xdata-de.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{AEEHHL2003a-ed}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Ágel, Vilmos et al., eds. (2003). Dependency and Valency. An International Handbook of Contemporary Research. Vol. 1. Handbücher zur Sprach- und Kommunikationswissenschaft 25. Berlin: De Gruyter. doi: 10.1515/9783110141900.1.]

Comment: oh. That's cool! Some things are so simple! =:-)

Comment: I now try to work with these xdata bibtex entries. While creating a bib file with the command `biber --output_format=bibtex --output-legacy-date bib-creation.bcf -O gt_tmp.bib`, the xdata field disappears. It would be good if it could be expanded during the creation. Is this possible?

Comment: @StefanMüller There is an option called `--output-resolve-xdata` that may or may not help here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked!

Comment: The multiscript version of biblatex and biber are now in CTAN as separate packages `biblatex-ms` and `biber-ms`. They can be installed in parallel with the normal packages to try out. Feedback welcome.